# Why we have to wait for sometime to get latest group info from UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups method?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

We have an AD user, say **userA**, which is the member of **GroupA**, **GroupB**.

Using **UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups** method gives those Groups.

Then we add userA to another group, say **GroupC**.

But just after adding to the new group and running UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups method still shows GroupA, GroupB. **It doesn't show GroupC**.

If we wait for sometimes (around 10 minutes) OR switch user and sign in again then only UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups method shows GroupC along with GroupA, GroupB.

**Why do we have to wait or sign in again to get the latest value?**

For **UserPrincipal.GetGroups method**, we don't have to wait or sign in again. We are using the **UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups** method as we need the nested group also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the specific implementation is not to be 100% trusted. The user groups get cached and the function does not take that into account.

Suffice it to say, it does make sense in most if not all cases. The new groups apply after login and querying the AD for every retrieval seems like an overkill.

For more and a solution check here: https://milestone.topics.it/2012/12/userprincipalgetauthorizationgroupsoh-my.html

```
IEnumerable<String> GetGroups( String samAccountName )
{
    var userNestedMembership = new List<string>();

    var domainConnection = new DirectoryEntry();
    domainConnection.AuthenticationType = System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

    var samSearcher = new DirectorySearcher();

    samSearcher.SearchRoot = domainConnection;
    samSearcher.Filter = "(samAccountName=" + samAccountName + ")";
    samSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add( "displayName" );

    var samResult = samSearcher.FindOne();

    if ( samResult != null )
    {
        var theUser = samResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
        theUser.RefreshCache( new string[] { "tokenGroups" } );

        foreach ( byte[] resultBytes in theUser.Properties[ "tokenGroups" ] )
        {
            var SID = new SecurityIdentifier( resultBytes, 0 );
            var sidSearcher = new DirectorySearcher();

            sidSearcher.SearchRoot = domainConnection;
            sidSearcher.Filter = "(objectSid=" + SID.Value + ")";
            sidSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add( "name" );

            var sidResult = sidSearcher.FindOne();
            if ( sidResult != null )
            {
                userNestedMembership.Add( ( string )sidResult.Properties[ "name" ][ 0 ] );
            }
        }
    }

    return userNestedMembership;
}
```